# how to generate microsoft visio file with diagram in apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to generate visio diagram in java with apache poi.
I have some search and can not find any good example for do this.
I want to create uml diagram and export this diagram to a visio file.
What is the best solution for this reason ?

Comment: According to [their official website](http://poi.apache.org/components/diagram/), I would say that it is not possible

Comment: You could maybe bounce off some .net code, but that might be a bit too much effort: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258882/generate-visio-diagram-on-the-fly-with-net